# I have a list that contains only strings even with numbers, I want to convert only the number values to ints and leave everything else as strings

Tags: python, list, iteration

Here is what I tried:

```
g = ["5", "-2", "4", "C", "D", "9", "+", "+"]

new = [int(x) if x == str(range(-100, 100)) else x for x in g]

print(new)
```

Comment: What is ` if x == str(range(-100, 100))` supposed to do?? Have you checked what `str(range(-100, 100))` range gives you? It gives you a `str`, `'range(-100, 100)'`... is that `==` to any of the other items in your list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test for integers by stripping off a potential `-` and then testing if the rest `isnumeric()`. For example:

```
g = ["5", "-2", "4", "C", "D", "9", "+", "+"]

new = [int(x) if x.lstrip('-').isnumeric() else x for x in g]

print(new)
# [5, -2, 4, 'C', 'D', 9, '+', '+']
```

**Edit:**

As others have pointed out, there are other edges cases which are not in your input. A more robust solution would to define a function that explicitly determines how you want to convert the strings...something more like:

```
g = ["5", "-2", "4", "C", "D", "9", "+5", "+", "-", "--3", "⓪⑧"]

def str2int(s):
    try:
        return int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s
    
new = [str2int(n) for n in g]
[5, -2, 4, 'C', 'D', 9, 5, '+', '-', '--3', '⓪⑧']
```

Comment: what about "--3" ?

Comment: `if x.lstrip('-').isnumeric()` is generally not the right approach for this. Rather, you should *try to convert to `int`* and if it succeeds, then you have an int. If it doesn't, you dont'

Comment: Also "+3" converts to a proper integer but would be skipped by this approach.

Comment: I'd be curious how you would handle the string `"--3"` @AlainT. I think the question is a good point and a reminder that the solution depends on the input data. If `--3` or `+3` are possible inputs, you will need to adjust accordingly (for example including `+` in the strip).

Comment: "--3" should be processed as a string.  If edge cases are not covered, they should at least be mentioned (e.g. as a disclaimer).  Actual use is rarely limited to one example, otherwise why write a program at all.

Comment: Gotcha...I thought you were implying that `--3` should be `3` as it would be if used as a literal — which is what I think the intent would be if that appeared in this list. Again — it depends on the input and how it's interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your strategy is to generate a set of strings that correspond to the possible numbers and check if each string is in that set.

Here's how you could do it:

```
numbers = set(str(x) for x in range(-100,100))
new     = [ int(x) if x in numbers else x for x in g ]
```

This limits you to a specific range of numbers which you need to know in advance (it also doesn't cover cases such as "+3" or "005").

A common way to do this is to "ask for forgiveness rather than permission", which means try to convert every item to a number and use the original string if it fails:

```
new = list()
for x in g:
    try:    
        new.append(int(x.strip()))  # try to add x as an integer
    except ValueError: 
        new.append(x)       # use original string if it fails
```

If you must do it in a list comprehension, you can use the .isdigit() method of strings but you have to take into account the + or - sign that may be at the first position:

```
new = [int(x) if x[x[:1] in "+-":].isdecimal() else x for x in g]
```

*Note, i'm using . isdecimal() instead of .isnumeric() or .isdigit() to avoid getting errors converting special characters such as '一二三四五' or '2²' for which isnumeric()/isdigit() is True but cannot be processed by int().  There is also the case of leading/trailing spaces which this doesn't cover.  With all the edge cases to handle, the try/except approach seems a lot simpler/safer.*

Comment: upvoted and took the liberty of using standard indentation and specifically catching a ValueError ... bare except clauses are pretty much never the right thing